# Stripping timezone from datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I am trying to strip timezone from the column 'ds'

```
ds
2023-06-01 00:00:00+00:00
2023-06-01 01:00:00+00:00
2023-06-01 02:00:00+00:00
2023-06-01 03:00:00+00:00
2023-06-01 04:00:00+00:00
```

Tried the following code :

```
Usage_df_V2['ds'].astype(str).str[:-6] but it strips off the hours as well:

2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-01 00:00:00
2023-06-01 00:00:00
```

Also tried the tz_convert but it strips of the time

```
Usage_df_V2['ds'].dt.tz_convert(None)
```

& get the following:

```
2023-06-01
2023-06-01
2023-06-01
2023-06-01
2023-06-01
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: do you want to remove the time zone from the *data structure* or do you want to *display* the data in a certain format, i.e. without the UTC offset / time zone information? For example, if a pandas datetime is *displayed* as `2023-06-01`, that does not mean that the hour isn't defined; it is rather just zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right. You can drop the timezone like so:

```
Usage_df_V2['ds'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```